# How to split a string and get middle characters using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, string, url, split

I have a URL with below format:

```
example.com/test/label-name/abc123

example.com/test/label-name/abc123/status-name/
```

I need to get the string "abc123" in the above cases. The above cases occurs randomly. How can I use a if condition here?

I have tried using Split() and Contains() in different ways. It is of no use. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: The string you want to obtain will occur in the same place everytime? Like it cannot change places right

Comment: Pretty sure you're looking for `window.location.pathname.split('/')[3]`

Comment: Do you always want to get the string after 3rd '/'? Does your URL pattern changes?

Answer (score 0):

If the position of "abc123" doesn't change in the URL sample you provide you can use the following:

```
var url = 'example.com/test/label-name/abc123/status-name/';
var splitURL = url.split('/');

var result = splitURL[3];
if(result == 'abc123'){
    alert('Hey! I got abc123');
}
```

No matter what the url, it will always give you whatever is there in that position.

Comment: But the string "abc123" also keep changes. only the /label-name/ and  /status-name/ are constant. Can I get it in this case ?

Comment: You can put an if statement there. So the `alert` will only appear when you have 'abc123', check out my edited code

Comment: That's not the point. I need whatever the string that appears in place of "apc123" irrespective of the URL. The only constant condition is /label-name/ and /status-name/. Anything between these two strings is needed.

Comment: Then the code that I have sent you will work... Just do `splitURL[3]` you will get whatever is at position three. Are you saying that the position of abc123 changes as well? like url can be `example.com/test/something/label-name/somelabel/status-name/`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, assuming your URL structure doesn't change, you will always be interested in the 3rd string element like so

```
var url = 'example.com/test/label-name/abc123/status-name/';
var splitURL = url.split('/');

var result = splitURL[3];
```

result should always give you the value where "abc123" is.